# How to parse string that are not standardized JSON in ruby?

Tags: json, ruby, fluentd

I am using fluentd to parse logs, which looks like:

```
{ date="2017-04-01 10:22:18.306", message="This is a trace Message!" }
{ date="2017-04-01 10:22:18.306", message="This is a debug message" }
```

While standardized JSON version is supposed to be:

```
{ "date":"2017-04-01 10:22:18.306", "message":"This is a trace Message!" }
```

I have tried

```
str='{ date="2017-04-01 10:22:18.306", message="This is a trace Message!" }'
Yajl::Parser.parse(str)
```

And it does not work:

```
Yajl::ParseError: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                     { date="2017-04-01 10:22:18.306",
                     (right here) ------^

    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1/lib/yajl.rb:37:in `parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1/lib/yajl.rb:37:in `parse'
    from (irb):45
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: @EricDuminil I have updated

Comment: @Pao : What's the result that you get from your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regex:

```
data = %q(
{ date="2017-04-01 10:22:18.306", message="This is a trace Message!" }
{ date="2017-04-01 10:22:18.306", message="This is a debug message" }
)

pattern = /date="([^"]+)", message="([^"]+)"/

messages = data.scan(pattern).map{ |date, message|
  {date: date, message: message}
} 

p messages
# [{:date=>"2017-04-01 10:22:18.306", :message=>"This is a trace Message!"}, {:date=>"2017-04-01 10:22:18.306", :message=>"This is a debug message"}]
```